Cryogenic pump - why is this part slotted?
What is the purpose of that slotted area?
In my opinion it is done that way in order to prevent it (the impeller) from sticking to the pump body in case it is not properly cooled down.
Some people say it is a labyrinth seal but the teeth dont match in a labyrinth way.



it's a diagram, it's unlikely they will spend the time to make the labyrinth seal be truly accurate.

I'm not sure it is physical slotting... What you are seeing could be to denote some lubricant or grease?

It is indeed physical. I will take some photos tomorrow.
